# Is there any benefit to leveling 1* or 2* cards?

Tags: guardian-cross

I'm saving all my fodder for when I get atleast 3* or higher cards, but I see players in coliseum who have upgraded their 2* cards.

Is this just a short term strategy that uses up extra cards at hand for a quick power boost now, or am I missing something and the lower level cards are also worth leveling up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few low level guardians worth upgrading as **debuffers**, i.e. they are used as sacrificial lambs to weaken strong enemy cards so that either

- your stronger guardians can follow up with a kill
- enemy guardian can't OHKO (one hit kill) your guardians

An example is the 1* guardian ***Slime***, which can have 3 debuffs at lvl 30. Such cards can be used to good effect unless your entire deck consists of high end 5* cards.

Other than such cases of debuffing, you should not waste GP & resources to level up 1*-3* cards and save them for 4* or 5* instead.